# Android Studio modo Design cinza

Tags: android, android-studio

Comprei um aplicativo na *codecanyon* e estou editando aos poucos tudo e concertando, porém tem uma coisa que estou estranhando, talvez seja algum problema bobo porém não consigo resolver o mesmo.

[image: http://prntscr.com/ib07t9]

Comment: Poste o seu código ou algum erro que aparece no LogCat.

Comment: Olá Valdeir, obrigado pela resposta e a disposição em me ajudar, o erro que está apresentando é o seguinte http://prntscr.com/ib0mp1, talvez eu não fui tão claro no que eu queria explicar, geralmente era pra aparecer o modo design para que eu possa editar o menu e etc certo?
porém ele só demonstra essa tela cinza e falando sobre o android... CordinatorLayout

Comment: Clique no ícone de alerta que fica ao lado dos botões de zoom e da mãozinha. Ele vai mostrar o log de erros do pré-visualizador. Cole aqui o que aparece lá.